# Error : Called function should be payable

Tags: solidity, remix, tokens, payable, javascript-vm

I am trying to create a token contract and the token sale contract.

Token Contract : ERC20 token is ready and it is flawless
TokenSale Contract : I have passed the "Token"" contract to "TokenSale" and created it. It has the function "pushTokens". It just pushes the coins from owners address to beneficiary address

When I tested in remix using "JavaScript VM" environment, I have the issue in the below location where I transfer the created ERC20 tokens, it fails. I am not able to understand the issue.

I have changed the ownership to "TokenSale" Contract

*Note : I don't receive the ETH from user while they using the "TokenSale" contract*

Source code of contracts (Flattened file)

**Token**     : https://textuploader.com/1e2jg

**TokenSale** : https://textuploader.com/1e2jx

**Relevant code from Token Contract**

```
library SafeERC20 {
using SafeMath for uint256;

function safeTransfer(IERC20 token, address to, uint256 value) internal {
    require(token.transfer(to, value));    **---------  Issue Line -------**
}
```

**Relevant code from TokenSale Contract**

```
contract TokenSale is Crowdsale{
  
event CrowdsaleFinalized();

constructor(   
ERC20Mintable token
)

public
Crowdsale(token)  
{ 
    require(address(token) != address(0),"Token is not an address");   
}   

}




contract Crowdsale is ReentrancyGuard {
using SafeMath for uint256;
using SafeERC20 for IERC20;

// The token being sold
IERC20 private _token; 

// Amount of wei raised
uint256 private _releasedToken;

event TokensPurchased(address indexed purchaser, address indexed beneficiary, uint256 amountOfTokens);

constructor (IERC20 token) public { 
    require(address(token) != address(0)); 
    _token = token;
}

function () external payable { 
}


function token() public view returns (IERC20) {
    return _token;
} 

function releasedToken() public view returns (uint256) {
    return _releasedToken;
}

function pushTokens(address payable beneficiary,uint256 rate,uint256 amountOfTokens) public nonReentrant payable  {
    _preValidatePurchase(beneficiary, rate, amountOfTokens);

    // update state
    _releasedToken = _releasedToken.add(amountOfTokens);

    _processPurchase(beneficiary, amountOfTokens);
    emit TokensPurchased(msg.sender, beneficiary, amountOfTokens);

    _updatePurchasingState(beneficiary, amountOfTokens);

    _postValidatePurchase(beneficiary, amountOfTokens);
}


function _preValidatePurchase(address beneficiary, uint256 rate, uint256 amountOfTokens) internal view {
    require(beneficiary != address(0)); 
    require(rate > 0); 
    require(amountOfTokens > 0); 
}


function _postValidatePurchase(address beneficiary, uint256 amountOfTokens) internal view {
    // optional override
}

function _deliverTokens(address beneficiary, uint256 tokenAmount) internal {
    _token.safeTransfer(beneficiary, tokenAmount);  
}


function _processPurchase(address beneficiary, uint256 tokenAmount) internal {
    _deliverTokens(beneficiary, tokenAmount);
}


function _updatePurchasingState(address beneficiary, uint256 amountOfTokens) internal {
    // optional override
}

}






contract TokenSale is Crowdsale{
  
event CrowdsaleFinalized();

constructor(   
ERC20Mintable token
)

public
Crowdsale(token)  
{ 
    require(address(token) != address(0),"Token is not an address");   
}
```

}

**Error Location**

[image]

**Error**

[image]

**Deploy / Run**

[image]

Comment: Please post **ALL** the relevant code and **ONLY** the relevant code, in **PLAIN-TEXT** which allows copy/paste (i.e., no links or images).

Comment: @goodvibration I have added the code so that it is easy for copy / paste. Please ignore the images, it may help others. Thanks !

Comment: @iappmaker Who account owns the tokens on sale? The TokenSale contract, Token contrar or the owner account?

Comment: @Ismael I have changed the ownership to "TokenSale" Contract. Even then the issue persists.

Comment: @iappmaker I have tried the code in remix and when tokens were deposited in the TokenSale contract it worked as expected.

Comment: @Ismael  I just added the deploy / run screen.. Not sure if there is some correction needed. Please advise

Comment: @iappmaker You should deploy TokenSale, not Crowdsale (in this case it isn't the cause of the error because TokenSale does nothing). Did you transfer some tokens to the TokenSale contract? TokenSale tries to transfer its own tokens, if it doesn't have any it fails.